# Submitting search query to Yahoo Web Search from Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, yahoo-search

I want to perform a search query from my rails app, which uses the Yahoo Web Search service, and parse the response from the yahoo api, and populate the database based on this response.

I wanted to know how can I go about submitting this query from my app in rails. And also, if there are any gems which let you do the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BOSSMan gem created by Jay Pignata should work.

http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-and-yahoo-boss-with-bossman-1047.html